# How can I pass smarty variable to .js file for var definition?

Tags: javascript, file, variables, smarty, assign

I have in php getting id from server request for parameter id

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$smarty->assign('id', $id);
```

And in the smarty .tpl display files {$id} outputs the number to the client browser.

I need this variable in the javascript for the page:
    `var id = {$id};`

I use id later in the javascript to define datatables default search value.

`"oSearch": {"sSearch": offer_id},`

My problem is I need to properly pass the id to the javascript, if is set at all. Right now it displays {$id}. Any ideas, please?

Comment: Your JavaScript is on your .tpl file or in a .js file ?

Answer (score 0):

In your template (`.tpl`) file, include the code

```html
<script>
  var id = {$id};
  console.log(id); // for debugging purposes
</script>
```

In your browser's Javascript console, you should be able to see the value of `id`.